# Errors trying to flatten JSON in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to learn how to use Spark to process JSON data, and I have a fairly simple JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"key": { "defaultWeights":"1" }, "measures": { "m1":-0.01, "m2":-0.5.....}}
```

When I load this file into a Spark dataframe and run the following code:

```
val flattened = dff.withColumn("default_weights", json_tuple(col("key"), "defaultWeights")).show
```

I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'json_tuple(`key`, 'defaultWeights')' due to data type mismatch: json_tuple requires that all arguments are strings;;
'Project [key#6, measures#7, json_tuple(key#6, defaultWeights) AS default_weights#13]
+- Relation[key#6,measures#7] json
```

If I change my code to make sure both arguments are strings, I get this error:

```
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
       val flattened = dff.withColumn("default_weights", json_tuple("key", "defaultWeights")).show
```

So as you can see, I am literally going around in circles!

Answer (score 2):

`json_tuple` could work if your `key` column would be a text and not a struct. Let me show you:

```
val contentStruct =
"""|{"key": { "defaultWeights":"1", "c": "a" }", "measures": { "m1":-0.01, "m2":-0.5}}""".stripMargin
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("/tmp/test_flat.json"), contentStruct)

val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
   .appName("Spark SQL json_tuple")
   .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._
sparkSession.read.json("/tmp/test_flat.json").printSchema()
```

The schema will be:

```
root
 |-- key: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- defaultWeights: string (nullable = true)
 |-- measures: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- m1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- m2: double (nullable = true)
```

So de facto, you don't need to extra the `defaultWeights`. You can simply use them with JSON path (`key.defaultWeights`):

```
sparkSession.read.json("/tmp/test_flat.json").select("key.defaultWeights").show()
+--------------+
|defaultWeights|
+--------------+
|             1|
+--------------+
```

Otherwise, to use `json_tuple`, your JSON should look like that:

```
val contentString =
"""|{"key": "{ \"defaultWeights\":\"1\", \"c\": \"a\" }", "measures": { "m1":-0.01, "m2":-0.5}}""".stripMargin
```

In that case, the schema will be:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- measures: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- m1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- m2: double (nullable = true)
```

And:

```
sparkSession.read.json("/tmp/test_flat.json")
      .withColumn("default_weights", functions.json_tuple($"key", "defaultWeights")).show(false)
```

will return:

```
+----------------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|key                               |measures     |default_weights|
+----------------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|{ "defaultWeights":"1", "c": "a" }|[-0.01, -0.5]|1              |
+----------------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```